# ui table view cell reorder *without* shadow

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, shadow

I have a uitableview and when I put it in the edit mode and reorder the cells , the native ui shows the cells separators/shadow while I drag the cell.
Is there a way to drag the cell without the shadow being visible ?
I have already set the setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone on my table view, however the shadow is still visible for cell being dragged.
Thanks!